# Launching application with NSPasteboard data

Tags: cocoa, nspasteboard, appleevents

I would like to launch applications (or send to them using AppleEvents) using NSPasteboard data just like is done in the Finder when you drag and drop a file, text, image on an application (or in the Dock) and it launches or invokes the data in the app.

Launch services functions like LSOpenFromURLSpec work only for files and I see there is an option to arbitrary parameters of AppleEvents but I could not figure out how to make this work.

Another question would be is the sandboxable but I'm not sure it's possible at all yet.

Thank you.

Comment: So you just want to launch a specific application and send it a document to open?

Comment: I know how to launch documents but I'm interested in other data like text, images which they may accept (as defined in the info.plist Document types). Basically I want to programmatically drop some data on another app and get the same effect as if the data was dropped on the application in the Finder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're the receiver, what happens depends on what the user is dropping:

- #### One or more files

  The application is sent one or more open document Apple Events. NSApplication tries to send at least one (should really be only one, but this has been broken for a few versions) message to its app delegate before trying the document controller.
- #### One or more URLs (not of the file: scheme)

  The application is sent one or more get-URL events. You'd need to implement an Apple Event handler for this. Conveniently, this is the example [the Apple Event handling documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_handle_AEs/SAppsHandleAEs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001239-BBCBCIJE) uses.
- #### Any other data

  You need to [implement a service](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/). Which service will be used for Dock drops is auto-detected based on types, and I don't know how it picks among multiple matches; there's no way to specify only certain services as being available to the Dock. You guessed correctly with regard to NSPasteboard: You implement services using pasteboards for I/O.

---

When you're the sender:

- #### Sending files

  The easiest way is to use Launch Services. This will send the appropriate Apple Events on your behalf.
- #### Sending URLs

  Again, Launch Services will send the requisite Apple Events for you. Indeed, in modern code, you'll probably use the same LSOpen API(s) for both file and non-file URLs.
- #### Sending any other data

  As the receiving application must implement a service, so must you [perform a service](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSPerformService).

  The hard part is discovery: you need to know which service you want to perform, and it needs to be available. I assume that you know which application you'll be sending to (simulating a drop onto), which is a leg up on most people who'll intend to send to a service. I'm pretty sure you'll just have to look at the target application's Info.plist and find which service best matches the types you have yourself.

  One potential wrinkle is that you can't specify an application bundle. You'll have to hope that the targeted application's services are enabled to show up in the Services menu, and you'll have to figure out the correct menu item name yourself. (Experiment with what's showing up in your own Services menu to try to derive the correspondence.) Even if you come up with the correct service item name and the service is enabled, there's no guarantee that the service will be performed by the application in the bundle you were looking at—it may be a different version or even (possibly, depending on how the names are constructed) a different app that has a service with the same name.

  You may want to [file a Radar](https://bugreport.apple.com/) about this.

Comment: This addresses how the target app responds to the drop but I'm interested in how I could package data from my app and "send" it to another app (i.e. drag on to) in a way that would invoke that same response (depending on the data sent). With files and URL's this is possible using Launch Services but I don't know how this could be done for arbitrary data except for maybe AppleEvents in some way. Thanks.

Comment: @GenericPtr: D'oh. I even understood that earlier and then forgot. Sorry. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I don't think services are the correct route because many apps can accept drops of various data types yet they have registered no service for them. I do this in my own apps for example to accept text drags to create new files.

Comment: Never mind! There is a service I registered to accept text drags. If I have to invoke services by menu item names without a bundle ID then I don't see how this could possible work and may require reading info.plists which I think is not possible in sandboxing. The service that allows TextEdit to accept text is named "New TextEdit Window Containing Selection" but it does not appear in the Services menu (same for the service my app uses). Thanks.

Comment: @GenericPtr: Every service is disabled by default unless it specifies a context (even if the context spec is empty). This may or may not be intentional in TextEdit's case. At any rate, you can turn on any service that's present on the system in the Keyboard prefpane.

Comment: I just tried this an passing a NSPasteboard data from a drag to TextEdit using NSPerformService does work but it relies on me knowing the service name. As far as I know this list is not exposed anywhere and since Apple is forcing sandboxing we can't read other apps info.plist. I may be able to make this work but it will require  extra work for users no thanks to sandboxing.

Comment: One last thing I found there is a utility which will show all registered services using /System/Library/CoreServices/pbs -dump_pboard. Apple suggests not to use it in production code and the results are returned as a text property list (non-XML) and I'm not sure how to parse this using Cocoa yet.

Comment: @GenericPtr: If it's a plist, NSPropertyListSerialization should work, but running pbs without running into the walls of your soundbox will be tricky.